# Spring Boot update field in database hardcoded

Tags: spring, jpa, nativequery

i have this in my repository

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE pengajuan u set u.status_approval ='Komite' where u.id_pengajuan =:idPengajuan",
        nativeQuery = true)
void updateStatusPengajuan(@Param("statusApproval") String statusApproval, @Param("idPengajuan") Integer idPengajuan);
```

**i want to set status_approval to 'Komite' by 'idPengajuan'**

now i have this in my services

```
    public PengajuanK3 update(String statusApproval,int idPengajuan){
    return pengajuanK3Repository.updateStatusPengajuan(statusApproval, idPengajuan);
}
```

im littlebit confuse how i can call the repository in services because in repository is void type.

Comment: Well, you change the return type to void, and you remove the `return`. Note that your repository method is wrong: it ignores one of the parameters.

Comment: @JBNizet is the query right? for harcoded? or i need to add something in my controller?

Comment: @YohanesEAC why are you sending statusApproval as a parameter in the updateStatusPengajuan method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that you have used always sets `status_approval` to `Komite`. In this sense, you don't need to pass the parameter in your repository update method. Everything is fine.

But if you want to update `status_approval` dynamically from the parameter other than 'Komite' then do like this:

Repository:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE pengajuan u set u.status_approval =:statusApproval where u.id_pengajuan =:idPengajuan",
    nativeQuery = true)
void updateStatusPengajuan(@Param("statusApproval") String statusApproval, 
@Param("idPengajuan") Integer idPengajuan);
```

And in your service change the return type to void and remove return.

```
 public void update(String statusApproval,int idPengajuan){
     pengajuanK3Repository.updateStatusPengajuan(statusApproval,idPengajuan);
}
```

In your controller, call the update method like:

`service.update('Komite', 1);`

I prefer this way rather than hardcoding because in the future if you need to set `status_approval` to other values, you can do it by:

`service.update('othervalues', 1);`